# How to profile code in julia?

Tags: julia

I have a program in julia and I know it took a lot of memory. I want to know where it is happening. 
How can I monitor the code or profiling for finding the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read the manual: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/profile/index.html
Profiling for memory use discussed at the bottom. The Juno IDE has some nice tools for interacting with the profiler: http://docs.junolab.org/latest/man/juno_frontend/#Profiler-1